# Using an HTTPS URL or IP address doesn't work in JavaZOOM JLayer

Tags: java, internet-radio, jlayer

I have used JLayer to implement this radio:

```
public class RadioImplement {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            //works fine
            //  playRadioStream ( "http://kantipur-stream.softnep.com:7248" );
            //hitsfm works fine
            // playRadioStream ( "http://webstream.hitsfm.com.np:5098/" );

            playRadioStream("http://108.166.174.131:8002/;stream.mp3"); //doesnt work
            //playRadioStream(" https://radio.itechnepal.com/kanchanjunghafm/stream"); doesn't work either says 403 forbidden
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (JavaLayerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void playRadioStream(String spec) throws IOException, JavaLayerException {
        // Connection
        URLConnection urlConnection = new URL(spec).openConnection();
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Playing
        Player player = new Player(urlConnection.getInputStream());
        player.play();
    }
}
```

The IP address URL and web stream doesn't work. In web stream, it uses `https://` and says it is forbidden, and the IP address gives some errors. What can I do to solve this problem?